# OpenCV Video streaming from FLIR Camera using Python

Tags: python, opencv, flir

I am having trouble streaming from a FLIR Grasshopper3 to OpenCV. Is there a way to stream directly from the FLIR camera to my code using python? When I use the code below, cv.Videocapture is not able to recognize the FLIR camera as a video source. I have tried different values in cv.Videocapture. While 0 and -1 link to the webcam app I use (iVcam), using different numbers that should find other Camera sources (1 and 2) do not identify the FLIR camera.

```
import numpy as np
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util 
import cv2 as cv
from time import time


cap = cv.VideoCapture(1)

while (True):
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    print(frame.shape)
    cv.imshow('frame',frame)

    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0XFF == ord('q'):
        break 

cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Desktop\flirtest.py", line 10, in 
    print(frame.shape)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: You might want to consider using this public repository for FLIR cameras: https://github.com/LJMUAstroecology/flirpy

Comment: And when you say it doesn't work, what do you mean? What is the error you receive?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Thanks for the Github link @aminrd. cv.VideoCapture is not able to identify the FLIR camera, only the webcam app I use (iVcam)

Comment: I have edited my question to include more information and the traceback, thanks for the feedback @furas

Comment: All FLIR/PTG cams need cam inits and return camera pointers to be enable to perform image acquisition. Have you found the Acquisition.py file in the example folder? And is the question still relevant?

Comment: @ZF007 yes I found the acquisition.py file from FLIR file and was to use that successfully

Comment: @aminrd Just a note that flirpy (I am the author) is for thermal imaging cameras, not for FLIR's visible imaging cameras.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the Acquisition.py and AcquisitionOpenCV.py files to integrate the camera into my code. The files can be found when downloading FLIR's Spinnaker SDK found here: https://www.flir.com/products/spinnaker-sdk/

Comment: Great to read you found it and also joy-able that Brain and colleagues from FLIR added the OpenCV variant based on the ImageEvent and ChunkData discussion I had with them.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of [Spinnaker SDK](https://www.flir.com/products/spinnaker-sdk/) does not have AcquisitionOpenCV.py file in it.
There is another file AcquireAndDisplay.py which works independent of OpenCV thus reducing the list of dependencies to display FLIR camera view.